# Android service getting foreground app

Tags: android, service

Im new to services, so i have a little problem here. Im trying to get foreground app name and i want to print it out with toast, bu i always get an runtimeException and i dont know why... Here+s the code:

```
public class ForegroundAppService extends Service {

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {        
    super.onCreate();
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Foreground service started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    try {
        ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) 
                    ForegroundAppService.this.getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        RunningTaskInfo runningTaskInfo = activityManager.getRunningTasks(1).get(0);            
        String foregroundTaskPackageName = 
                    runningTaskInfo.topActivity.getPackageName().toString();
        PackageManager pm = ForegroundAppService.this.getPackageManager();
        PackageInfo foregroundAppPackageInfo;
        foregroundAppPackageInfo = pm.getPackageInfo(foregroundTaskPackageName, 0);
        String foregroundTaskAppName = 
                    foregroundAppPackageInfo.applicationInfo.loadLabel(pm).toString();
        Toast.makeText(this, foregroundTaskAppName, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {         
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return Service.START_STICKY;
}

}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where do you get the exception? Please post stack trace and logcat

Comment: I get it in onStartCommand() method where ActivityManager is declared

Answer (score 0):

An Android Service lives on its own, without an Activity. You can bind an Activity to a service or start a Service from an Activity. In any case, as the Service has no Foreground Activity, the ActivityManager is not available and you get an exception.

What you can do is, have a look into the parameter `Intent` that you got in the `onStartCommand`. You find there some limited information about the sender of the intent. If you like to know more, you can add extra information to the Intent by the calling Activity with `Intent.putExtra()`.

If you want to closely bind an Activity with your Service use the `bindService` method for Activity. You can than send messages between them.